# How can I install EGOPhotoViewer in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to create a photo gallery in my app, I tried to use Three20 and EGOPhotoViewer. I would like to use EgoPhotoViewer but I am new at programming and I don't know how to install EgoPhotoViewer to my app. When I try to use it I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyPhoto", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in MasterViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyPhotoSource", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in MasterViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EGOPhotoViewController", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in MasterViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If EGOPhotoViewer is just a couple of classes (which is what it sounds like), then drag them into your project and #import and @class them in the proper files.  If it's a framework, then drag it into your project and make sure that it is being linked in build settings, then #import <> the necessary header.

Your undefined symbols error just means that you're trying to reference an invisible, non-existent, or out of reach class.

EDIT: For future reference because I know you're still a beginner.  When you see "Undefined symbols for architecture XXXX"; the XXXX is the MOST important part. If it says armv6 or armv7, then you have a device build problem.  If it says "i386", that's a simulator problem.  I'm going to guess that the classes for EGOPhotoViewer are universal, but there are cases where the dunderheads decided not to build for the simulator (Dropbox anyone?)  and undefined symbols for architecture i386 would come up.

Comment: I tried again, but I got this error when I try to implement the following codes:

Comment: if (indexPath.row == 0) {
  
        MyPhoto *photo = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/profile_images/425948730/DF-Star-Logo.png"] name:@"lskdjf lksjdhfk jsdfh ksjdhf sjdhf ksjdhf ksdjfh ksdjh skdjfh skdfjh "];
        MyPhotoSource *source = [[MyPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photo, nil]];
  
  EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:photoController animated:YES];
 }
}

Comment: I don't know. I copy this code from the Demo app. When I write into my own app I get the error, but when I delete it or do this /* */, it runs without error...

Comment: Run your code; then instead of pasting a comment, when the app crashes copy the information from the log and paste it as an edit to your own question.